# Pycairo fails to produce PDF when drawing 100's of fills

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

Drawing a trivial array of filled circles fails when more than about a thousand appear on a PDF surface, yet a PNG render of the same context has no problem. I have tried a range of solutions and cannot readily get an error message or other clues -- any ideas, please? (under Mac OS X 10.12.6, latest libraries installed)

```
import cairo

Pi=3.14159265

# this works, Python 2.7
surface = cairo.PDFSurface("cairoTest.pdf", 595, 842)
cntxt = cairo.Context(surface)
cntxt.set_source_rgb(.3, .1, .6)
for xstep in range(0,50,1):
    for ystep in range(0,31,1):
        cntxt.arc(xstep*10.+30, ystep*10.+30, 3., 0., 2.*Pi)
        cntxt.fill()

surface.write_to_png("example.png") # Output to PNG
surface.finish

# this produces zero-byte file 
surface = cairo.PDFSurface("cairoTestFkd.pdf", 595, 842)
cntxt = cairo.Context(surface)
cntxt.set_source_rgb(.3, .1, .6)
for xstep in range(0,55,1):
    for ystep in range(0,35,1):
        cntxt.arc(xstep*10.+30, ystep*10.+30, 3., 0., 2.*Pi)
        cntxt.fill()

surface.write_to_png("exampleFkd.png") # Output to PNG
surface.finish
```

Comment: `fails` means what? some circles were invisible or all were invisible? or something problems else?

Comment: Sometimes produces an unreadable file, but most often a zero-length PDF file.

Comment: surface.finish is a function

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be a strange MS Code (Visual Studio) issue: run from the command line, the above code produces good PDF, but run from inside Code it does not. Furthermore, it is only the last file/context processed that doesn't work (*and* is big enough or takes long enough to process?) so adding a dummy/extra context at the end "sorts this out". I suspect a synchronisation issue is at play, such as files being closed before a sub process has finished, buffers not flushed properly, etc.

Note that context.finish, context.flush make no difference to behaviour.

Comment: Did you try to actually call `surface.finish`? Your example has no `()` in it so does not actually call the function.